# When I use scp command through expect, asterisk can not recognized

Tags: linux, shell, tcl, sh, expect

Hello I have a one problem in linux shell

I write a scp script using expect and the script is like this.

```
#!/bin/sh

expect -c "spawn scp /tmp/data/*2017-06-14*.log2 id@localhost:~/"\
       -c "expect -re \"password\" "/
       -c "sleep 1" \
       -c "send \"password\r\""\
       -c "interact"
```

and result of execution shows error message.

```
/tmp/data/*2017-06-14*.log2 : No such file or directory
```

But When not use expect, scp execution is success

```
[user@localhost]# scp /tmp/data/*2017-06-14*.log2 id@localhost:~/"\
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Expect* does not understand shell's syntax. You can:

```
spawn sh -c "scp /tmp/data/*2017-06-14*.log2 id@localhost:~/"
```

or

```
spawn sh -c {scp /tmp/data/*2017-06-14*.log2 id@localhost:~/}
```

---

[komar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44579083/900078) using `glob` would not always work. See following example:

```
bash-4.4# expect
expect1.1> system pwd
/root/tmp/tcl
expect1.2> system ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 16 10:55 a  b
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 16 10:55 c  d
expect1.3> spawn ls -l [glob *]; expect eof
spawn ls -l {a  b} {c  d}
ls: cannot access {a  b} {c  d}: No such file or directory
expect1.4> spawn sh -c "ls -l *"; expect eof
spawn sh -c ls -l *
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 16 10:55 a  b
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 16 10:55 c  d
expect1.5>
```

Comment: So, how can i scp without password input in your solution?

Comment: just update your `spawn` (in the first `-c ...`) command and keep other `-c ...` as is.

Comment: Comment is too late. Thanks your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need globbing in expect/tcl style:

```
expect -c "spawn scp [glob /tmp/data/*2017-06-14*.log2] id@localhost:~/"
```

Comment: the `glob` way does not always work. just updated my answer by adding an example.