# Expect script: How to archive and delete files from it?

Tags: bash, file, expect

I want to use pure expect script without calling external shell to do tar and rm operations. My current result is working, but with external bash script.

P.S. All my attempts to exec tar or rm from expect script are failed.

**Main script**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
# my scripts folder is here:
set myhome /home/scripts
set fullBpath /home/backup/SDH/
set date [exec date +%F_%k-%M]
# Some expect script commands was removed here.
exec $myhome/zip_clean.sh $fullBpath $date
send_user "Script terminated.\n"
exit
```

**zip_clean.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $1
tar cvzf OME6500-Backup-$2 *.cmp *.inf
rm *.cmp *.inf
```

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44559187/

Answer (score 0):

You can use command [file](http://wiki.tcl.tk/file) and command [glob](http://wiki.tcl.tk/glob). Also
for working with date you can use [clock](http://wiki.tcl.tk/clock):

```
set date [clock format [clock seconds] -format %Y-%m-%d_%k-%M]
cd $fullBpath
exec tar cvzf OME6500-Backup-$date [glob *.cmp *.inf]
file delete [glob *.cmp *.inf]
```

Comment: `system "cd $fullBpath; tar cvzf OME6500-Backup-$rundate.tgz *.cmp *.inf; rm *.cmp *.inf"`

Comment: your example produce error in tar execution. Archive created empty and script terminated.

Comment: `glob` returns a list of filenames, and tar expects not a list but each individual element. Try this: `set files [glob *.cmp *.inf]; set status [catch {exec tar cvzf $tarfile {*}$files} output]; puts $output; if {$status == 0} {file delete {*}$files}` -- the `{*}` syntax expands the list in-place (see [rule 5](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm) of the 12 syntax rules of Tcl)

Answer (score 0):

Found and tested very simple way:

```
system "cd $fullBpath; tar --remove-files -cvzf OME6500-Backup-$rundate.tgz *.cmp *.inf"
```